# How to achieve Self healing mechanism in automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, artificial-intelligence

I am working on application where the elements are changing frequently so we have to update the locators(xpaths or CSSselectors) manually which takes manual effort. There are many tools in the market which uses AI to perform self healing. How can we implement self healing mechanism in the automation framework(Selenium with Java). Could anyone know the AI libraries or the process to achieve this  self healing in the normal frameworks.

Comment: _"elements are changing frequently"_ what are these elements? _"update the locators manually which takes manual effort"_ what does _locator_ mean in your context? What are you refering as a _"self healing mechanism"_?